# What is an example of LOCC measurement which is not separable?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-measurements

Could you give me an example of a measurement which is LOCC (Local Operations Classical Communication) but not separable?  Or better, one which is separable but not LOCC?

Given an ensable of states $\rho^{N}$, a separable measurement on it is a POVM $\lbrace N_i \rbrace$ where the effects $N_i$ are all of the form $N_i = A_i^{1} \otimes A_i^{2} \otimes \dots \otimes A_i^{N}$. So they are a separable product of effects acting on each state $\rho$ in $\rho^{N}$.

Is every separable measurement LOCC?

---

***[Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5839/55)***

Comment: Cross-posted on [QCSE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5839).

Comment: What do you mean by "separable"?

Comment: Aren't separable POVMs *more* powerful than LOCC ones?

Comment: Yes indeed, I made a bad mistake in formulating the question. I want a separable operation that is non LOCC. I corrected the mistake. I just have never seen a counterexample to all separables are LOCC.

Comment: @MrRobot How do you expect people to put any effort in their answer if you don't even put enough effort in your question to get the basic direction of the main logical implication right?

Comment: Also, your edit makes my answer invalid. Can you find a way to edit your question without invalidating existing answers, e.g. by adding your new question, or asking another question altogether?

Comment: ok, btw it is not the first time I look for a counterexample but didn't find the paper. I think LOCC != separable is known to qinfo students much more than the actual counterexample.

Comment: @MrRobot By your practice of editing the question again to change its meaning, I look like a fool who was unable to read your question.  To me this is very bad practice.  Do you mind preserving the old question and extending it?

Comment: MrRobot, edits which change the meaning of a post --- especially edits which invalidate existing answers --- [are discouraged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/editing).  I've tried to preserve both your original question and your intended meaning.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't: Any LOCC measurement is also a separable measurement.  This is easy to see: Alice's first measurement has POVM elements $A_{i_1}\otimes I$. Alice then communicates her outcome $i_1$ to Bob.  Bob's subsequent measurement has elements $I\otimes A^{i_1}_{i_2}$, where $i_2$ enumerates Bob's outcomes, and $A^{i_1}$ indicates that Bob's POVM can depend on Alice's outcome.  The total POVM of both has then elements
$$
N_{i_1,i_2}=A_{i_1}\otimes B^{i_1}_{i_2}\ ,
$$
 which is a separable POVM with double index ${i_1,i_2}$.  Clearly, this can be iterated to an arbitrary number of rounds, and generalized to an arbitrary number of parties, and will always have POVM elements of the form $N_i=A_i\otimes B_i\otimes \cdots$.

Conversely, not every separable POVM can be written as a LOCC POVM. A counterexample is given in [Bennett *et al.*, Quantum Nonlocality without Entanglement](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9804053), [Phys. Rev. A. 59, 1070 (1999)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.59.1070).